# Unable to restore a pg_dump using psql containing unicode character

Tags: postgresql

I am able to successfully dump a database using a command similar to the one below:

```
pg_dump -h hostserver -d databasename -U username | gzip > sqlfile.sql.gz
```

However, I'm unable to restore this file.
Command used:

```
gunzip -c sqlfile.sql.gz | psql -h hostserver -U username databasename
```

A little digging brought me to the error:

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "columnname"
```

I was able to look through the sql.gz file created by pg_dump and found that the offending record has all the columns, but psql can't read passed the U+001A unicode character contained in it.

Is there any way to get psql to correctly read this file?
Or is there a way I can get pg_dump to export a file that psql will be able to read?

**Edit**
Isolating the error:

```
ERROR:  missing data for column "streettype"
CONTEXT:  COPY address, line 284167: "-776257   1   \N  \N  \N  CRIPPLE CREEK"
invalid command \N
```

streettype is the next expected column in the data.
However, the import failed while reading

```
CRIPPLE CREEKCASINO
```

And this is the unicode break down of the offending text:

```
U+0043 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
U+0052 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
U+0049 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
U+0050 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
U+0050 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER P
U+004C : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER L
U+0045 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
U+0020 : SPACE [SP]
U+0043 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
U+0052 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER R
U+0045 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
U+0045 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER E
U+004B : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER K
U+001A : <control-001A> (SUBSTITUTE [SUB])
U+0043 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
U+0041 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A
U+0053 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S
U+0049 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I
U+004E : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER N
U+004F : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER O
```

Comment: Are you doing this on windows?

Comment: Yes, I am running this on windows.

Comment: Then you'll somehow have to trick psql into reading the file in binary mode. Windows treats Ctrl-Z as a virtual end-of-file marker in text mode.

Comment: I tried your file on Linux and had no problem. So maybe @melpomene got it right. In that case, I would say that it is a PostgreSQL bug, and you should report it as such. Unfortunately I have no Windows to try this on.

Answer (score 1):

As @melpomene said, windows treats Ctrl-Z as a virtual end-of-file marker.

by changing the pg_dump output format to either directory or tar format and restore using pg_restore works.